# Vectors from functions in tikz 3d plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, vector

I designed this graphic but now I want to make a change.
I would like to sample with 10 points the three functions that define the coordinates x, y, z. I would then create 10 vectors that depart from the origin and end in each of the points obtained.
I hope I explained clearly.
Anyone have any idea of how to do this?

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9] 
\begin{axis} [view={10}{10}, xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, zlabel style={rotate=-90},xmin=0,ymin=0,zmin=0] 
\addplot3 [domain=0:9, samples=40,samples y=0, smooth,thick,blue] ({3.286*cos(25.8)+1.55*(0.1278*ln(1000*x)-1)*cos(67.1)},{0.1278*1.55*ln(1000*x)*sin(67.1)},{x}); 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution: the "quiver" option which adds to the chart arrows of given length and origin defined by a function.

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[view={100}{70},xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,zlabel style={rotate=-90},xmin=-3.5,ymin=-3.5,zmin=0,xmax=3.5,ymax=3.5,zmax=9]
\addplot3[red,/pgfplots/quiver, samples=10, domain=0.001:9, variable=\t,quiver/u=3.286*cos(25.8)+1.55*(0.1278*ln(1000*t)-1)*cos(67.1), quiver/v=0.1278*1.55*ln(1000*t)*sin(67.1), quiver/w=0, quiver/scale arrows=1,-stealth] ({0},{0},{t});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```